# Location of start-up configuration files - Firefox launching at startup, Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: startup, cron, bug-reporting, ubuntu-mate, metapackages

My problem is simple. Firefox is launching by itself at startup. I can't disable this and if I try to purge it then it tries to also uninstall MATE desktop WTF ??!!

The question is which are the configurations that run at start-up, I know CRON but is there another configurations is this game ?

I don't need to disable it since is just a *preference* to have the DE do as I say but I can close Firefox each time. I had the start-up option of remembering the already opened applications on and switched it off, restarted, yet had the same result.

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox && sudo apt-get install -y firefox
[sudo] password for mateuser: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox* ubuntu-mate-core* ubuntu-mate-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 107 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

[Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1574645)

```
sudo find ~ -name firefox* | grep firefox
[sudo] password for user
/home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox
/home/user/.mozilla/firefox
```

In the meantime I simple changed the name of the program binary. Wild situations require wild measures.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to either *autostart* or *cancel autostart* for any given app upon login, You can:

**A)** go to the Dash, and open "Startup Application". Select the application you want to not autostart anymore and hit the button "Remove".

or

**B)** go to yr terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type:

```
 $ cd ~/.config/autostart ; ls -AF

 # check that you see the file `firefox.desktop`

 $ mv firefox.desktop firefox.desktop_bak
```

You're done and the next time you launch a gui session, fx should not launch on its own. 
You don't need to purge an app to prevent it from autostarting. The autostart config has nothing to do with the app itself.

Comment: Firefox is not there :/

Comment: @user3005629: Can you edit your initial post  by adding the result of : `sudo find ~ -name firefox* | grep firefox` in terminal ?